# taglist in iterm2

Tags: iterm

I use [taglist vim plugin](https://github.com/int3/vim-taglist-plus) in iterm2

when I use `:TlistToggle`, the first time is ok

[image]

but the second time of `:TlistToggle`, I get

[image]

any suggestions ?

PD: I don't have this problem in fullscreen

Comment: for now, I will use https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar

Answer (score 1):

I finally found which iTerm2 feature causes this bug, see [my blog](https://oracleyue.github.io/2018/05/06/taglist-iterm2/).

To fix it, go to

`iTerm2: Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal -> uncheck "Disable session-initiated window resizing"`

[image]